# how do I display data to a text area in html from any sort of input aka text box or database in asp.net core ( runat doesnt work or pop up)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

i can't find anything that tells me how to display data to a text area from a database or textbox without using runat or tells me how to use run at, what i am trying to do is this ,  I have text boxes and a submit button when the button is pressed it must display to the text area , I've tried run at , I've googled and I can't find a straight answer that shows me how to do it.

I've tried the run at method doesn't work nor does it pop up.

I've tried googling and no luck

Comment: As per [ask] please post a [mre] of your issue showing relevant code. Please also state clearly your version of .NET and the flavour of asp.net you're using (e.g. mvc, razor pages or whatever). You've tagged it with .net core but AFAIK the `runat` syntax only applies to the legacy WebForms framework, so it's a bit unclear if you've just been searching for entirely the wrong thing, or you're on the right track but just applied it incorrectly, or are using the wrong tool for the job - there's only a fairly vague description of what you want, too. That's why your post is downvoted and closed

Comment: It's possible the answer below is what you need, but equally it could be totally irrelevant. There isn't enough info for anyone to be sure. 50% of what you've written is just a complaint rather than meaningful info

Comment: @ADyson that's my issue i cant give you an example of code cause i don't even know where to begin with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to display data to a text area from a database

You can refer to the below demo.

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            TextInputModel model = new TextInputModel();
            model.list = new List<string> { "answer1", "answer2", "answer3" };
            model.Name = "aa";//you can get your data from batabase too...
            return View(model);
        }
```

TextInputModel:

```
public class TextInputModel
    {
        public List<string> list { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model TextInputModel 


<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">List</label>
            <textarea name="list" class="form-control" style="text-align:right">@string.Join("\n ", Model.list)</textarea>
        </div>
        
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <textarea name="Name" class="form-control" style="text-align:right">@Model.Name</textarea>
        </div>
```

result:
[image]

> I have text boxes and a submit button when the button is pressed it
> must display to the text area

I create a view to show text box and a view display data to a text area.

Controller:

```
        public IActionResult Show()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Show(string Name)
        {           
            ViewBag.Name = Name;      
            return View("ShowText");
        }
```

Show view:

```
<form method="post"  asp-action="Show">
    <input type="text"  name="Name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

ShowText view:

```
<textarea name="Name" class="form-control" style="text-align:right">@ViewBag.Name</textarea>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: @QinqGuo it partly did i realise I'm trying to jump into advanced coding without knowing how to do the controlers ect so i need to lean to make that stuff